# Spring Cloud Contract - empty path parameter randomly generated from the regexp

Tags: java, spring-cloud-contract

I am trying to introduce path param in `urlPath` as regexp in the following way:

```
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

Contract.make {

    request {
        description("""
Represents a success scenario for searching Location Groups.
""")
        method 'GET'
        urlPath(value(regex('/trackedItems/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/locationOccupancies'))) {
            queryParameters {
                parameter 'groupId' : anyNonBlankString()
            }
        }

    }
    response {
        status OK()
        body(
            objects: [
                id : $(anyPositiveInt()),
                locationName : $(anyNonBlankString()),
                locationDescription : $(anyNonBlankString()),
                locationType : $(anyNonBlankString()),
                locationEntry : $(iso8601WithOffset()),
                locationExit : $(iso8601WithOffset()),
                trackedItemId : $(fromRequest().path(1)),
                trackedItemQuantity : $(anyPositiveInt()),
            ]
        )

    }
}
```

In general it seems to work, however sometimes java tests are getting generated with empty parameter in path:

```
// when:
            ResponseOptions response = given().spec(request)
                    .queryParam("groupId","WMGOAMYTVGOBBZXADCRU")
                    .get("/trackedItems//locationOccupancies");
```

In the same time Wiremock mapping looks just fine:

```
{
  "id" : "0919f4ee-d487-415e-aaa2-eefbd19833f9",
  "request" : {
    "urlPathPattern" : "/trackedItems/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/locationOccupancies",
    "method" : "GET",
    "queryParameters" : {
      "groupId" : {
        "matches" : "^\\s*\\S[\\S\\s]*"
      }
    }
  },
  "response" : {
    "status" : 200,
    "body" : "{\"objects\":{\"id\":527805002,\"locationName\":\"UWHAHTXXYOZNEOKNKGTC\",\"locationDescription\":\"JQZGDLZTXCAUAITPYJLX\",\"locationType\":\"JVUVLFHVBXWHSMACUZUL\",\"locationEntry\":\"0737-06-03T21:45:28+06:24\",\"locationExit\":\"3625-06-03T23:14:29Z\",\"trackedItemId\":\"{{{request.path.[1]}}}\",\"trackedItemQuantity\":1392018943}}",
    "transformers" : [ "response-template", "spring-cloud-contract" ]
  },
  "uuid" : "0919f4ee-d487-415e-aaa2-eefbd19833f9"
}
```

Is there something wrong with my contract? Maybe there is a better way to do this?

```
id "org.springframework.cloud.contract" version "3.0.1"
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.1.RELEASE'
```

Thanks!!

Edit:
Same for id "org.springframework.cloud.contract" version "3.0.2"

Comment: shouldn't you change * into + in the regex? * means zero or more, right?

Comment: Well, you may be right. I have changed it and it worked couple of times so far. However let's wait for the final thoughts :): previously it also worked few times at the very beginning. In general I am surprised how often it generated the empty value. Not good at "probability" at all but the ratio of failures were >50%.

Comment: I've added an answer - can you please mark this question as answered?

Comment: Wow. you were quick:). I edited my comment in the meantime. Let's wait for some time (max: day) and I will close it if no further issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the regex. Instead of `/trackedItems/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/locationOccupancies` there should be `/trackedItems/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/locationOccupancies`